# Get DOM elements of a popup for jQuery manipulation

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup

I am creating a popup as follows:

```
   var comet = {

        popup: null, 

        newPopup: function(windowsname, w, h){
            this.popup = window.open(windowsname, windowsname, 'width=' + w + ',height=' + h);
            var self = comet;
            var logOut= null;
            $(this.popup.document).ready(function(){
                logOut = self.popup.document.getElementById('logout');
                console.log(logOut);
                $(logOut).live('click', function(){
                    alert('HELLO');
                    return false;
                })
            })
        },

        some_function: function(){
             //calling it here:
             this.newPopup('index.php',1120,550);
        }
    }
```

The `logOut` sometimes (usually on the 1st window open) returns null. Also, the click handler never goes through and the original click handler operates.

How do I overwrite the real click handler of the popup?
 Both pages are on my site, so there should be no cross site issues..

Here is a fiddle that shows a little of what I am trying to do: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/K2B3q/

Comment: @Matt, sorry ill add that to my question. `comet` is the object name

Comment: Why don't you include the JS that you want to operate on the page in the popup in the popup index.php file itself, rather than in the main document?

Comment: @maxedison, i want to let the main page (that created the popup) know that `logOut` was clicked

Comment: Ok, so why not just write `var self = this;`? Also, any particular reason you're not using a modal dialog instead of a popup?

Comment: @MattBall, i tried that but was getting errors, thats even the reason why there is a `var self`

Comment: @MattBall here is a sudo fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/K2B3q/

Comment: @MattBall, the popup is a configuration page. there is alot that would be going on there, not just a a plain ol' popup

Comment: I have a solution which works (for me) in FF4 and Chrome. See my edit, let me know what you think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested and working in Firefox 4 and Chrome 11. [Check it out.](http://jsbin.com/eriwo4/5/)

```
$(function()
{
    var comet =
    {
        popup: null,  
        newPopup: function(url, w, h)
        {
            this.popup = window.open(url, url, 'width=' + w + ',height=' + h);
            var self = this;

            this.popup.onload = function ()
            {
              var doc = this.document,
                  script = doc.createElement('script');
              script.src = 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js';
              script.onload = function ()
              {
                  function setup()
                  {
                      $('#logout').click(function () { alert('It worked!'); });
                  }

                  script = doc.createElement('script');
                  script.textContent = "(" + setup.toString() + ")();";
                  doc.body.appendChild(script);
              };

              doc.head.appendChild(script);
            };
        },

        foo: function()
        {
            this.newPopup('http://jsbin.com/amuza3/2', 600, 400);
        }
    };

    $('#clickme').click(function ()
    {
        comet.foo();
    });
});
```

Comment: @MattBall, yes but the element **should** be there. especially on popup load, no?

Comment: @MattBall, your update doesnt seem to be doing anything (im in chrome, ddnt see your note abt chrome), this has to work in chrome

Comment: I'm curious to know why, if the popup page is fully in your control, you can't just add the script you want to execute into the page - what's the motivation for controlling the popup from the parent?

Comment: @MattBall, the reason for that is that i need to **close** the child window when logout is clicked on the child, and there is the same logout button on the parent (using the same click handlers) so if i add it to the child, it would be added to the parent (which i do not want)

Comment: @Matt, i just looked at you newest code, and im going over it

Comment: I tryed adding a `win = this` after the `doc` declaration and `win.close()` after the `alert('It worked!');` but it did not close the window

Comment: @Neal that's because, to get this working in Chrome, I had to create a function (in this case it's called `setup`) that gets injected into a `<script>` tag in the child window, as a string. This is necessary to properly detach from the parent window - there's no actual closure created because `setup` is just turned into a string. You can just use the normal `window` variable inside of `setup` and it will correctly reference the popup.