# jQuery - how to set callbacks to parent page in a popup

Tags: jquery, callback, popup

When i open a popup, i want to be able to set few callbacks that the popup can call. 
So basically i'd have two pages with code like this:

```
*****popup.html*******
var callBack;
function OnSaveClick()
{
  if (callBack)
     callBack();
}

**********************************************
********popupOpener.html*************
function callBackHandler()
{
   //some code here
}
function OpenPopup()
{
   var p = window.open("popup.html");
   p.callBack = callBackHandler;
   return false;
}
```

The problem with this is that var callBack gets reset when the DOM of popup.html loads and it doesn't load until OpenPopup() on the opener completes.
So the next best thing would be to set the callBack in the ready event of popup.html. But i want to be able to attach an event handler to the ready event of popup.html in popupOpener.html.
So the OpenPopup function would now look something like this:

```
var p;
function OpenPopup()
{
  p = window.open("popup.html");
  $(p).ready(hookCallBack)      //doesn't work
  //or $(p.document).ready(hookCallBack)  //doesn't work
  return false;
}
function hookCallBack()
{
  p.callBack = callBackHandler;
}
```

But hookCallBack() executes immediately after $(p).ready(hookCallBack) and NOT when the DOM of popup.html is ready. Is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See my question: [Get DOM elements of a popup for jQuery manipulation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5984463/get-dom-elements-of-a-popup-for-jquery-manipulation) for an answer of how to control the popup after it is loaded

So you can do something like @MattBall's answer:

popupOpener.html:

```
var opener = {

        popup: null, 

        newPopup: function(windowsname){
            this.popup = window.open(windowsname);
            var self = this;

            this.popup.onload = function ()
            {
              var doc = this.document,
                  script = doc.createElement('script');
                  script.src = 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js';
                  script.onload = function ()
                  {
                      function setup()
                      {
                          //something to do on the popup
                      }

                      script = doc.createElement('script');
                      script.textContent = "(" + setup.toString() + ")();";
                      doc.body.appendChild(script);
                  };

                  doc.head.appendChild(script);
            };
        },

        some_function: function(){
             //calling it here:
             this.newPopup('popup.html');
        }
    }
```

So to load the popup on page load:

```
window.onload = function(){
    opener.some_function();
};
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/EJasA/

Comment: I don't know why but popup.onload = someFunc;  someFunc never gets called after popup DOM loads. I'm testing in IE.

Comment: where did you get `popup.onload`?   all you have to do is `opener.some_function();`

Comment: Yeah this works. This is as elegant as you can make it. Thanks a ton buddy.

Comment: i spoke too soon i guess. this.popup.onload = function () the function never gets called on the load of the popup. I checked in your code sample too. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

in your popup page refer to "opener" to get the page which created the popup:

so for example:

```
function OnSaveClick()
{
  if (callBack) //just have callback as a boolean field
      opener.top.frameFocus.callbackfunc();
}
```

see http://www.webreference.com/js/tutorial1/opener.html

Comment: This is not an option as we don't want popups to be tied to a particular parent page. This popup works with many pages and they may have a callBackfunc or may not. And we want to eliminate this opener kind of code as much as possible as there is just lot of interaction. We want some kind of contract between page and popup.

Comment: I'm not with you - this doesn't "tie" a pop-up to a parent. Any pop-up created has a reference to it's creator. If the parent does not want to be called back then set callback = false when creating the popup.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(callback_function) {
   eval('window.opener.' + callbak_function)(name, age, address);
}
```

callback_function is string