# How to access DOM (and /or window.document object) of a popup in Chrome extension script?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm working on a Google Chrome 'context' script

From the Chrome console, or a 'normal'  tag, I can do :

```
win1 = window.open('some url'); 
b1 = win1.document.body.innerHTML;
```

But from a chrome 'context' script, it fails with

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'document' of undefined

What is the "magic incantation" I need ?

This seems to be close to what I need, but it doesn't show where to put code to have the popup return a dom element
[Get DOM elements of a popup for jQuery manipulation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5984463/get-dom-elements-of-a-popup-for-jquery-manipulation)

I don't fully understand the code there (nested scopes and things), so
I'm trying to figure out where I'd put something like:

```
var getStuff = $('#baz').html();
```

Mike

Comment: If you can describe what you are trying to do at the end, maybe someone can suggest a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

You can only do what you propose **IF** both urls are in the **same domain**.

Otherwise you have cross domain issues and chrome (and most other browsers) do not allow for it.

Comment: They *are* in the same domain (localhost://<same directory for both files>file1... file2 , .. isn't "localhost://" the domain ?

Comment: I'll try to add something like 127.0.0.1 tester.domain.com to my hosts file, and see if that makes a difference