# Load code when I open a popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, popup, styles

I need to load some code JS when I load a popup window. I've tried with:

```
mypopup.ready(function...
```

But nothing.

Here's my code.

```
  function popup(){
   mypopup = window.open('http://33bits.es/foro/masiconos.php', 'popup', 'width=400','height=300','status=no', 'scrollbars=yes', 'toolbars=no', 'menubar=no', 'location=no');

}

 $('#mas').click(function(evt) { popup();  });

mypopup.ready(function() {


//Más Iconos
$('img').click(function (evt) {
   var clase =  $(this).attr('class');
   insertar_popup(clase);
});
$('.cerrar').click(function(evt) { window.close(); });


//Mas Iconos CSS
$('.cerrar').css("font-family", "Arial");
$('.cerrar').css("cursor", "pointer");
$('.cerrar').css("margin", "50%");
$('.pop').css("background", "url(http://www.33bits.es/foro/Themes/epic_2_0/images/id/abgg.png)");
$('.iconos_pop > img').css("margin", "5px");
$('.iconos_pop > img').css("cursor", "pointer");
$('.iconos_pop').css("border-radius", "10px");
$('.iconos_pop').css("padding", "10px");
$('.iconos_pop').css("background", "white");
$('.iconos_pop').css("margin", "5% auto");
$('.iconos_pop').css("width", "95%");
});
```

I want to load the popup and then, load this part of my code, it will give style to the popup. But it doesn't load and my popup doesn't have style, it seems empty and shabby.

Answer (score 1):

A potential solution to your problem could be the use of **jQuery Dialogs**. It appears the code that you want to load styles the dialog on open, but using jQuery Dialogs allows you to style it with CSS directly. Follow the link below for examples, as well as source code for initializing it.

http://jqueryui.com/dialog

The basic setup uses jQuery notation, you create a  in your html page and add a "dialog" class to it:

```
$(function(){
    $("#yourDialog").dialog();
})
```

Now to have it open on click of a link, you will need to add some options to the code so that it does not open by default and only when you click on a button that activates it:

**Javascript**

```
$(function(){
    $("#yourDialog").dialog({
        autoOpen: false 
    });

    $("#yourButton").click(function(){
       $("#yourDialog").dialog("open");
    });
})
```

**Html**

```
<div id="yourDialog" title="Basic dialog">
    <p>This is the default dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.</p>
</div>

<button id="yourButton">Button</button>
```

For a more complete example, visit the link http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form.

Comment: Note that OP asked for popup manipulation, not dialogs. These kind of suggestions are good but should be written as comments of the question

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I would've left a comment but alas I have yet to reach the required rep to do so. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Because you're modifying attribues of DOM elements in your main page, not the popup.

Moreover, `mypopup` variable isn't set when you attempt to call its `ready` method. You could try the following:

```
function popup() {
  var mypopup = window.open('http://33bits.es/foro/masiconos.php', 'popup', 'width=400', 'height=300', 'status=no', 'scrollbars=yes', 'toolbars=no', 'menubar=no', 'location=no');

  mypopup.onload = function() {
      var doc = mypopup.document,
          $popDocument = $(doc);

      // Everything you want
      $popDocument.find('.popClass').click(function() {
        alert('Hey you clicked in the popup!');
      });
  };
}

$('#mas').click(popup);
```

See it in action: http://plnkr.co/edit/u4YvcFtL1aUiVdmCMVhU?p=preview

Note that you should not manipulate your popup's contents by doing like `$('selector')` because it will search in you main page. Instead in the example above, do `$popDocument.find('selector')`.

Here is an answer that wraps the popup in an object in a nice way: [Get DOM elements of a popup for jQuery manipulation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5984463/get-dom-elements-of-a-popup-for-jquery-manipulation)

Comment: It doesn't work for me :(

function popup(){
  var mypopup = window.open('http://33bits.es/foro/masiconos.php', 'popup', 'width=400','height=300','status=no', 'scrollbars=yes', 'toolbars=no', 'menubar=no', 'location=no');
   mypopup.focus;

   $popDocument = $(mypopup.document);

   $popDocument.ready(function() {

     //Más Iconos
  $popDocument.find('img').click(function (evt) {
     var clase =  $(this).attr('class');
     insertar_popup(clase);
  });

Still like before.

Comment: Ok it was not that easy to make it actually work. Inspired on the other post I linked, I'll edit my post

Comment: Thanks @blint Let me know when you have something new. I keep thinking :D

Comment: Done. In fact it's that easy ;-) but we have to be really strict with these manipulations. Note that in the plnkr I added some contents to an empty popup for the testing purpose. In your case, you just have to write your logic/css changes in the `mypopup.onload` function

Comment: Yeaaaaah. But I have another problem, I have two click functions whicn doesn't work. 

I have one to close the popup by clicking in the word "Close" and another to click in an icon and add some text in a textarea in the main window. 

Here you have the code for those functions: http://pastebin.com/Xzp7JfM2

Thanks a lot. If you solve me this I'll build a golden statue of you xD

Answer (score 0):

That's becaus you can not edit the styling of another webpage that your request in your popup. That would be a security issue if it where possible.

if "http://33bits.es/foro/masiconos.php" is one of your own pages you could edit that and use

document.ready to do the styling

Comment: I do not think you can Apply styling to another webpage using javascript. That would mean you could send and recieve cookies from that website page as Well giving you unautherized access

Comment: It's solved here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27422796/load-code-when-i-open-a-popup/27422911?noredirect=1#comment43292389_27423246

But I have some new problems, could you help me? :)